# Split string in half and change case accordingly

Tags: python, strings, programming-challenge

I found the following challenge online:

> Create a function that takes a string and returns that string with the first half lowercased and the last half uppercased.
>
> eg: `foobar == fooBAR`
>
> If it is an odd number then 'round' it up to find which letters to uppercase.

That sounded easy enough but I found the last requirement a little tricky. Eventually this is what I came up with:

```
def sillycase(silly):
    length=len(silly)
    firstHalf = silly[:length / 2 + (length % 2)].lower()
    secondHalf = silly[length / 2 + (length % 2):].upper()
    return firstHalf + secondHalf
```

but that seems repetitive and inefficient.

What could I have done to make it slicker, without sacrificing readability? I was actually a *little* surprised python didn't have a built in method to split a string in half.

Comment: Regarding the last requirement: What about the [ceil function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.ceil)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Midpoint math is often a pain in the whatnot, but a real trick is to add 1 to the length before halving it. Additionally, instead of repeating the math multiple times, you can do it just once.

```
def sillycase(silly):
    mid=(len(silly) + 1) / 2
    firstHalf = silly[:mid].lower()
    secondHalf = silly[mid:].upper()
    return firstHalf + secondHalf
```

At that point, it becomes small enough to not need the temp variables:

```
def sillycase(silly):
    mid = (len(silly) + 1) // 2
    return silly[:mid].lower() + silly[mid:].upper() 

print (sillycase("hello"))
print (sillycase("helloa"))
print (sillycase("helloab"))
```

http://ideone.com/CqUdl5

Note the use of the integer divide which is suitable for both python 2.x and 3.

Comment: It might be/certainly is over expressive but i'd be tempted to return `""` on `mid==0` to be explicit.

Comment: @AidenBell - it certainly could be more efficient for sillily small sillies, but the simple `mid==0`would fail to process 1-letter values, like.... "i"... where mid would be 0, but the caps would still need to happen. Perhaps you meant `len(silly) == 0`?

Comment: Yes, of course that would be more correct. How silly of me ;)

Comment: I'm just mentioning it for completeness, but personally I find [`- (-x // y)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17511341/1763356) should be the canonical code for "round-up" division: it's lossless, works on Python 3, doesn't involve constants, always works for negative divisors and even works for floating point.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I'd just go for brevity and ensure the function name is expressive:

```
def silly_case(input_string):
    return "".join([char.lower() if index < (len(input_string) + 1)/ 2 else char.upper() for index, char in enumerate(input_string)])
```

EDIT:

I've gotten lots of criticism for my answer for stuffing things to one line, but I'm still a fan of list comprehensions, and I find it completely intuitive.  Based on the feedback, here's how I would implement this function:

```
def silly_case(input_string):
    pivot_index = (len(input_string) + 1) / 2
    char_list = [char.lower() if index < pivot_index else char.upper() for index, char in enumerate(input_string)]
    return "".join(char_list)
```

Comment: Brevity as a positive falls down when code isn't readable. Unreadable or unreasonable code costs more in terms of bugs than a few extra tokens. Perhaps i'm missing the point of the site, but if I saw this going in to production the author would be forced to rewrite it.

Comment: If a function is 1 line and it's well-named (here it's just "silly_case"), and there's test coverage for that function, do you still find that 1 line unreadable?  If anything I might change `(len(input_string) + 1)/ 2` to `pivot_index` and perhaps move `"".join(string_as_list)` to its own line but otherwise this seems like a straightforward list comprehension to me.

Comment: "If a function is 1 line and it's well-named (here it's just "silly_case"), and there's test coverage for that function, do you still find that 1 line unreadable?" ... yes, a million times yes. Character efficiency in code is not equal to computational efficiency, and even if it were, i'd still insist on a rewrite unless it was in some uber critical performance path. Yes, the situations in which this is acceptable IMHO are very, very rare. 99.99% of the time i'd take readable code over fast or succinct code.

Comment: In short, I see zero benefit to this being a long one liner vs a readable multiple line implementation ... that's ignoring the fact it is 129 characters long!

Comment: This looks more like golfing than good code, in my personal opinion.

Comment: not quite golfing, but two loops and an if stuffed into a single line???

Comment: I am slightly bewildered about the comments here.  I agree 1000% about code readability, but this is still a simple list comprehension.  To me, if you think this is unreadable then I would think you're in the camp that hates list comprehensions to begin with.  I was trying to offer a perspective to deal with the opinion that the initial code "seems repetitive and inefficient".

Comment: @RubberDuck it's one loop.

Comment: Sorry @ScottLobdell I was counting the `Join` which most likely does a loop internally.

Comment: @ScottLobdell - In fairness, this _is_ a code review site. I love list comprehension, but not at that price ;) Anyway, each to their own.